# Copying To Clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard, android-alertdialog

I want to bind `Copy to clipboard` functionality to `setPositiveButton` such that on clicking it, the text in `setMessage` gets copied to clipboard and the toast `Copied!` is displayed. 
Please help!

```
public void showDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Information!");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Mercury");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Copy!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismissed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();


}
```

Comment: It is unclear with what exactly you need help. Moreover 'Copied` is already displayed.

Comment: @greenapps : I just want the text in `setMessage` to be copied to clipboard when the `Copy!` is clicked.

Comment: Yes that i know already. But that involves several steps. So you have to tell exactly with which steps you need help.

Comment: @greenapps : Kindly elaborate me the steps

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will send the string "Mercury" to your clipboard. Change it for whatever you want.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("","Mercury");
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: I want to send the text appearing in `dialogBuilder.setMessage();` i.e. `Mercury`. How do I do that ?

Comment: Change "WHAT YOU WANT TO SEND TO CLIPBOARD" to "Mercury"

Comment: LOL :D I know that. But anyways, I figured another way out. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Well you hardcoded "Mercury". I don't where that value comes from so I can't provide you other ways set the text

Comment: But on your dialogBuilder.setMessage you have it hardcoded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60927/discussion-between-lance-preston-and-pedro-oliveira).

Comment: Because that's what the OP asked for. This will send "Mercury" to your clipboard

Comment: But you just send that string because you knew that that was set by setMessage(). But you should have done as if you did not know what was set. So use a getMessage() (if that exists). But the the OP did not elaborate on the steps... And did not show how he now gets it.

Comment: The rest of the discussion took place in the chat. The solution for that was to pass the string to the showDialog() method

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean would you care to clarify, IOW *explain*, what was wrong and *why* this works. "Try this code" answers, while acceptable, aren't very helpful because there's no context. IMHO, more-or-less worthless for the larger community.

Comment: The hate is strong in this one. "Answer is acceptable but I will just downvote it anyway"